# Find and Replace Text with RegEx in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, regexp-replace

Does anyone have an idea how I can achieve the following with Notepad++.

For example, I have the following text:

```
 { 1000000003;1;Column; ;
               DataSource=Search Name }

    { 10000004;1;Column; ;
               DataSource=Name 2 }
```

Is it possible to put the value that follows DataSource= in the line above?

The value is to be set after Column;.

The result should look like this:

```
{ 1000000003;1;Column;Search Name ;
               DataSource=Search Name }

    { 10000004;1;Column;Name 2 ;
               DataSource=Name 2 }
```

I have already created the following RegEx:

```
(;Column;)|(?<=DataSource=)\w+\s+\w+\.?)
```

With this I find what I need, but I did not manage to get the desired result with it.

Is this possible at all with RegEx or is there a plugin that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search using this regex with 3 capture groups:

```bash
(Column\s*;)\s*(;\s*DataSource=([^}]+))
```

and replace with:

```
$1$3$2
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QXC2tJ/1)

Comment: Can you please help me with this again?
`Column;Phone (No.)`
I would now like to remove everything after ;Column; that does not correspond to [A-z0-9].
I have tried this regex, but it does not work.
`(;Column;)*([A-z0-9]+)`
Substitution $1$2
https://regex101.com/r/LxhQ8g/1 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you want `Column;Phone (No.)` to become `Column;Phone No` or what?

Comment: Exactly. Only without spaces, i.e. `Column;PhoneNo`

Comment: Check this demo: https://regex101.com/r/LxhQ8g/2

Comment: Can this also be done as a replace variant?
So I would have to replace `Column;Phone (No.)` with `Column;PhoneNo`

Comment: No the one that I posted above is right approach that doesn’t assume any format of input data

Comment: Can you tell me what the solution would be if there were input data?

Comment: Sorry I am confused now. I have already given solution yesterday. May be you can post a new question to give more clarity of your problem so that we can give you best solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252602/discussion-between-user3644868-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it using Notepad++.

Use search and replace with the following search pattern:

`({.*?;)( )?(;.*?DataSource=)(.*?)( })`

and replace with:

`$1$4$3$4$5`

The logic behind it is matching all of your string with capture groups, before and after the part you want to replace, then re-building it with the same capture groups - only replacing the specific capture group of the replace point which is the second group `( )?` with the destination value group which is the fourth group `(.*?)`

Here is a [working example in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uvFVE2/1)

And a screenshot from *Notepad++*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks also for your help. This works just as well as the solution from @anubhava